# Facebook Feed Dialog Mobile Url: Issue with display=wap

Tags: facebook, dialog, wap, facebook-feed

I am using this url to direct my mobile web page to a facebook wall post dialog page, however I can't seem to get `display=wap` to work.

```
http://m.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=<myappId>&redirect_uri=<myRedirectUri>&link=<myLink>&display=<wap|touch>&picture=<myPicture>&caption=<myCaption>&description=<myDescription>&name=<myName>
```

Using `display=touch` works fine on most devices except some blackberries I've tested, where the dialog page is blank except for the "Publish" and "Cancel" buttons. When I use `display=wap`, I get "An error has occured" no matter what I do.

Does facebook support this feed dialog with display=wap? I found this url on their developer's web page here:
[Facebook Dialogs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/)
Under the heading labeled : **Mobile Display Modes**

I'd appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently we don't support the feed dialog in display=wap. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I had figured.