# can't display mobile dialog authentication on Nokia N70

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

Using of `mobile dialog authentication` is working well for other mobile devices except on this Nokia N70.

1) I call to graph api

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?type=user_agent&display=wap&client_id=xxxx&redirect_uri=xxxx&scope=user_photos,read_stream

2) which make for mobile devices to display the below uri
https://m.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?_path=permissions.request&app_id=xxx&redirect_uri=xxxx&display=wap&type=user_agent&xxx

But, it can't display the `2) step dialog` and automatically redirected to my redirect_uri which gave me errors of 404. Actually it show display authentication dialog box and should get grant from User.

What exactly might be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I can't find specific information on why it wouldn't work I would most likely suspect that because the N70 is a 6 year old phone and uses WAP 2.0, which Facebook actually hardly supports anymore as stated in numerous places. (e.g. [Facebook Feed Dialog Mobile Url: Issue with display=wap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627755/facebook-feed-dialog-mobile-url-issue-with-display-wap)

All modern handsets support full HTML these days. So WAP is mostly dead besides people who haven't updated their handsets in the last 3-4 years.

My suggestion is, why are you hoping to support WAP and is it really needed?

UPDATE [2012-07-07]: Facebook is now removing display=wap, hence making it completely dead in Facebook's world.

Comment: yes. I know that mobile phone is really old. but due to requirements, I need to cover for that mobile too. Thanks. plus 1.