# what is alternative solution for Removing display=wap Dialogs in Dialog Parameters of Facebook authentication?

Tags: java, facebook, sharing, facebook-authentication

Currently  i'm authenticating my facebook application passing parameter display=wap along with my authentication url. But it shows an error message  :" **An error occurred with 'App' on Mobile. Please try again later.
 API Error Code: 11
 API Error Description: This method is deprecated
 Error Message: Display=wap dialogs have been deprecated. You can temporarily enable them by disabling the 'july_2012' migration. They will stop working permanently on July 1, 2012.**"
When i disabled the 'july_2012' migration the authentication working properly. So how can i handle my apps after July and what is the proper & permanent solution for this issue.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6627755/facebook-feed-dialog-mobile-url-issue-with-display-wap

Comment: But when i use display=touch parameter, the same error is showing

Comment: Facebook don't support  display = touch for some devices. if you use the facbook sdk, try using display = popup ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/

Comment: But how 'popup' work on m. facebook.com(http://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=XXX&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2FXXX%3Farticle%3D11811755&state=12&scope=publish_stream&display=popup).It shows >> API Error Description: Invalid parameter
 Error Message: Display type popup isn't valid on m.facebook.com.

Comment: For which devices are you unable to get display=touch to work? It should work on all smartphones, mobile devices and small tablets.

Comment: @Matthew After 'july_2012' migration,there is  no problem

Answer (score 0):

Hi `display=touch` must work , If it does not work Use `Display=page` , This automatically converts facebook authentication for mobile site.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update to PHP SDK 3.0